# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Stays Expanded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried to search for this problem & found nothing!
Basically my navbar will not start collapsed on mobile. The menu stays expanded & i don't know why.

Check for yourself:
http://flux.network/wp/

Code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php bloginfo( $name ); ?></a>
        </div>

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
        ?>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="socialicons">
            <div class="form-group">
            <?php ?>
            <?php if ( ot_get_option('menu_search') != "off" ) { ?>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </form>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your navigation inside .navbar-collapse element. I can see comment on closing ".navbar-collapse", but can not see opening tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I id indeed miss an opening tag which was '<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">'

Comment: OK. If this resolve your problem, please mark this as answered.